# TensorFlow input value is not binary classification

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow, classification

I followed tensorFlow tutorials, but for my specific problem, I want the algorithm to know the exact value not either `<` or `>` to 50K like their example:

`df_train[LABEL_COLUMN] = (df_train["income_bracket"].apply(lambda x: ">50K" in x)).astype(int)`

Any ideas how to do so ?

Comment: It would help to have the complete example code you are working with, but given what you have written, simply not applying the lambda might do the trick (e.g. df_train[LABEL_COLUMN] = df_train["income_bracket"].astype(int)).

Comment: Thank you Joost. Actually the rest doesn't matter that much, It's just the that in their example they had binary classification (> or < to 50K). So they used that syntax, I'm new to tensorflow so I had no idea how to change it to accommodate my problem. I Will try your solution et give the feedback.

Comment: @JoostHuizinga It doesn't work!!

Comment: Ah, I see, it seems that df_train["income_bracket"] can literally contain the string ">50", so astype(int) will fail. You'll need to parse whatever is in df_train["income_bracket"] and convert it to numeric form. Exactly how to do that depends on what is in df_train["income_bracket"].

Comment: @JoostHuizinga I have floats, but  (df_train["income_bracket"].astype(float) doesn't work either